# JoinByArray filters and cursors

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a piece called **Article** which has a **joinByArray** field in its schema that relates to other piece called **Location**. When I create an Article, only **_ids** for locations selected.

In the Articles-page, I want to create a filter which initially shows a list of **all Locations** that have been assigned to Articles so far. After that, to let users click on any location to filter the list of articles.

It seems that when creating the 'location' filter from the scratch I need to create a join between the collection of Articles and collections of Locations so that I can display **location names**, instead of _ids.

1. Could you please give an example of how to do this?

Regarding, the joins and filters. At the moment, I have created different filters that work only by a single criteria. However, I'd like the user to be able to filter by multiple values in the same category and also multiple values in different categories.

2. I'm not sure if I need to create a different filter (adding the **marketAnd** for example) or If I have to add another option to the filters I already created.

I really appreciate your help with this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The majority of this issue can be solved with `piecesFilters` which allow you to create filters based on joins and have all the query string plumbing done for you.

http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/cursors.html#filtering-joins-browsing-profiles-by-market

I think it is up to you to concatenate the browser query string to filter a result set on multiple values of the same joined piece type, but that functionality does work out of the box if you get to

`/my-page?pieceType=foo&pieceType=bar`

Comment: ok thanks! I have checked that also it doesn't seem very clear. I am trying to creo a custom filter for markets as explained [here](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/cursors.html#custom-filters) But haven't been able to show the choices on screen. It works when I called `/my-pieces-page?pieceMarket=Canada` but if I go to `/my-pieces-page` where I am displaying the other filter options... this one doesn't list all options. Do you know how I can do this? The join I'm doing between the markets and Articles works but still it doesn't show options or stays in a loop.

Comment: Are you sure the pieces you're expecting are actually joined? If pieces A has a join to pieces B but no Piece As joins to Piece B[1], Piece B[1] will not appear in `data.piecesFilters`.

Comment: Yes they are joined. I have fixed this error as I was having an issue with the callbacks and join queries on **finalize** and **choices** functions at the cursors.js on my widget. So that's working fine now. However, If you could give a brief example on how the filter projections (specified on the joinByArray field on the piece schema) could be used, I really appreciated as I'm sort of confused on when they are useful and how I can used them. Thanks for the previous help and in advanced for the question below!

Comment: You want piece A to have a joinByArray to piece B and then on the index page of piece A you want to be able to filter by the join to B, yes?

After setting your `joinByArray` in piece A's schema, tell the `apostrophe-pieces-pages` module of piece A about the join you want to filter by. to do this, set a `piecesFilters` array in your pieces-pages configuration that contains objects of the names of Piece B.

Your index page should now a property `data.piecesFilters` that contains the URLs to construct the filtered index.

Comment: Code samples are here http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/cursors.html#creating-filter-u-i-with-code-apostrophe-pieces-pages-code